# Listen to events when app is closed - Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, notifications, chat, phonegap, strophe.js

How can I listen to events when my app is closed (not in background mode)?

I create chat app, with strophejs and I have listeners for messages, but they are working only when app is active or is in background. Is there a way to listen for this events when app is closed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this plugin : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Read first the Store Compliance information before continue, this is important.

Comment: I already check that lib, but it also handle only when app is in background mode. I need to listen to events when my app is closed. Also, I don't like idea of infinitive background tasks. I am looking for solution like push notification, which trigger event even when app is closed. 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you look about Firebase library for native push notification ?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I implement strophe.js in cordova, and changing to push notifications would require big changes in my code and logic. So I am looking for solution to put strophe.js listener for incoming message somewhere, where it will be triggered even when app is closed.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jasmeen There is no possible solution without using notification.
Using strophe.js or any other framework doesn't change anything.
To chat with the native system of the phone, you will have to use a cordova plugin.
Cordova create a browser that executes your JS code. If cordova is closed, your JS code does not exist and therefore cannot receive any events.